# Rationalise $\frac{2}{\sqrt{12}}$ fully

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I keep coming up with $\frac{\sqrt{6}}{6}$ but I don't think that it's right. Can you divide a surd by a common factor like $2$ to get rid of the denominator?

Would really appreciate it if someone could give me a step by step solution on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Is $3^{-1/2}$ what you're looking for?

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{12}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{4}\sqrt{3}}=\frac{2}{2\sqrt{3}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}\sqrt{3}}=\frac13\sqrt{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{2}{\sqrt{12}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{12}{2^{2}}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\cdot1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{1\cdot\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}\cdot\sqrt{3}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd simplify it:

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{12}} = 2 \times (12)^{-1/2} = 2 \times (2^2 \times 3)^{-1/2}  = 2 \times 2^{-1} \times 3^{-1/2} = 2^{1-1} \times 3^{-1/2} = 3^{-1/2}$$

If you want to rationalize it, just rationalize $3^{-1/2}.$

$$3^{-1/2} = 3^{1/2-1} = 3^{1/2}/3^1 = 3^{1/2}/3$$